# How to add store_id column on ui_component grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

In my custom module I am following same as cms page module. I added below code in my module ui_component file

```
<column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

I am getting below error:

> Notice: Undefined index: store_id in
>   D:\wamp\www\beta\pmagento2\vendor\magento\module-store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store.php
>   on line 82

Collection file code

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename;

class Collection extends \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection
{

   protected $_idFieldName = 'module_id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename', 'Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename');
        $this->_map['fields']['store'] = 'store_table.store_id';       
    }

    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $this->performAfterLoad('mytable_store', 'module_id');

        return parent::_afterLoad();
    }

    public function getAvailableStatuses()
    {
        return [self::STATUS_ENABLED => __('Enabled'), self::STATUS_DISABLED => __('Disabled')];
    }

    public function addStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true)
    {
        $this->performAddStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin);

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $this->joinStoreRelationTable('mytable_store', 'module_id');
    }

}
```

AbstractCollection code:

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename;

abstract class AbstractCollection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {        
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    protected function performAfterLoad($tableName, $columnName)
    {  
        $items = $this->getColumnValues($columnName);
        if (count($items)) {
            $connection = $this->getConnection();
            $select = $connection->select()->from(['cms_entity_store' => $this->getTable($tableName)])
                ->where('cms_entity_store.' . $columnName . ' IN (?)', $items);
            $result = $connection->fetchPairs($select);
            if ($result) {
                foreach ($this as $item) {
                    $entityId = $item->getData($columnName);
                    if (!isset($result[$entityId])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ($result[$entityId] == 0) {
                        $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores(false, true);
                        $storeId = current($stores)->getId();
                        $storeCode = key($stores);
                    } else {
                        $storeId = $result[$item->getData($columnName)];
                        $storeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
                    }
                    $item->setData('_first_store_id', $storeId);
                    $item->setData('store_code', $storeCode);
                    $item->setData('store_id', [$result[$entityId]]);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        if ($field === 'store_id') {
            return $this->addStoreFilter($condition, false);
        }

        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }


    abstract public function addStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true);

    protected function performAddStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true)
    {
        if ($store instanceof \Magento\Store\Model\Store) {
            $store = [$store->getId()];
        }

        if (!is_array($store)) {
            $store = [$store];
        }

        if ($withAdmin) {
            $store[] = \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;
        }

        $this->addFilter('store', ['in' => $store], 'public');
    }


    protected function joinStoreRelationTable($tableName, $columnName)
    {
        if ($this->getFilter('store')) {
            $this->getSelect()->join(
                ['store_table' => $this->getTable($tableName)],
                'main_table.' . $columnName . ' = store_table.' . $columnName,
                []
            )->group(
                'main_table.' . $columnName
            );
        }
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }


    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
        $countSelect->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

        return $countSelect;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you found any solution? My _afterLoad function not call. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The similar question was asked there: [Magento2: store_id in UI Listing Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99731)

Also, I recently successfully did it on Magento 2.0, and because of that I can help you to add **store_id column in ui_component**

1. In app\code\Company\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\company_module_news_listing.xml add the following column inside the columns node:

> ```
> <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
>     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
>         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
>             <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
>             <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
>             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
>         </item>
>     </argument>
> </column>
> ```

2. In app\code\Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\News\Collection.php add the following functions:

> ```
> /**
>  * Perform operations after collection load
>  *
>  * @param string $tableName
>  * @param string $columnName
>  */
> protected function performAfterLoadNews($tableName, $columnName)
> {
>     $items = [$this->getColumnValues($columnName)];
>
>     if (count($items)) {
>         $connection = $this->getConnection();
>         $select = $connection->select()->from(['news_store' => $this->getTable($tableName)])
>             ->where('news_store.' . $columnName . ' IN (?)', $items);
>         $result = $connection->fetchPairs($select);
>         if ($result) {
>             foreach ($this as $item) {
>                 $entityId = $item->getData($columnName);
>                 if (!isset($result[$entityId])) {
>                     continue;
>                 }
>                 if ($result[$entityId] == 0) {
>                     $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores(false, true);
>                     $storeId = current($stores)->getId();
>                     $storeCode = key($stores);
>                 } else {
>                     $storeId = $result[$item->getData($columnName)];
>                     $storeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
>                 }
>                 $item->setData('_first_store_id', $storeId);
>                 $item->setData('store_code', $storeCode);
>                 $storesIds = $this->getStoreIdsByTheNewId($item->getId());
>                 $item->setData('store_id', $storesIds);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * Join store relation table if there is store filter
>  *
>  * @param string $tableName
>  * @param string $columnName
>  */
> protected function joinStoreRelationTable($tableName, $columnName)
> {
>     if ($this->getFilter('store')) {
>         $this->getSelect()->join(
>             ['store_table' => $this->getTable($tableName)],
>             'main_table.' . $columnName . ' = store_table.' . $columnName,
>             []
>         )->group(
>             'main_table.' . $columnName
>         );
>     }
>     parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Finds store ids for the specified TheNew id
>  * @param  int $id - TheNew ID
>  * @return int[]   - store IDs
>  */
> public function getStoreIdsByTheNewId($newsId)
> {
>     /** @var array - store IDs */
>     $stores = [];
>
>     $connection = $this->getConnection();
>     $select = $connection->select()->from(
>         $this->getTable('news_store'),
>         'store_id'
>     )->where(
>         TheNewInterface::NEWS_COLUMN_NEWS_ID . ' = ?',
>         (int)$newsId
>     );
>     $stores = $connection->fetchCol($select);
>
>     // If no records found, TheNew is visible in All Store Views
>     if (count($stores) === 0) {
>         $stores[] = 0;
>     }
>     return $stores;
> }
> ```

3. In order to save, update and delete relations in news_store, add the following code in the model app\code\Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\News.php

> ```
> /**
>  * Assign The News to store views
>  *
>  * @param AbstractModel $object
>  * @return $this
>  */
> protected function _afterSave(AbstractModel $object)
> {
>     $oldStores = $this->lookupStoreIds($object->getId());
>     $newStores = (array)$object->getStores();
>     if (empty($newStores)) {
>         $newStores = (array)$object->getStoreId();
>     }
>     $table = $this->getTable('news_store');
>     $insert = array_diff($newStores, $oldStores);
>     $delete = array_diff($oldStores, $newStores);
>
>     if ($delete) {
>         $where = [TheNewInterface::NEWS_COLUMN_NEWS_ID . ' = ?' => (int)$object->getId(), 'store_id IN (?)' => $delete];
>
>         $this->getConnection()->delete($table, $where);
>     }
>
>     if ($insert) {
>         $data = [];
>
>         foreach ($insert as $storeId) {
>             $data[] = [TheNewInterface::NEWS_COLUMN_NEWS_ID => (int)$object->getId(), 'store_id' => (int)$storeId];
>         }
>
>         $this->getConnection()->insertMultiple($table, $data);
>     }
>
>     return parent::_afterSave($object);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Retrieve select object for load object data
>  *
>  * @param string $field
>  * @param mixed $value
>  * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $object
>  * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select
>  */
> protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
> {
>     $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);
>
>     if ($object->getStoreId()) {
>         $stores = [(int)$object->getStoreId(), \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID];
>
>         $select->join(
>             ['ns' => $this->getTable('news_store')],
>             $this->getMainTable() . '.' . TheNewInterface::NEWS_COLUMN_NEWS_ID
>                 . ' = ns.' . TheNewInterface::NEWS_COLUMN_NEWS_ID,
>             ['store_id']
>         )->where(
>             'ns.store_id in (?)',
>             $stores
>         )->order(
>             'store_id DESC'
>         )->limit(
>             1
>         );
>     }
>
>     return $select;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get store ids to which specified item is assigned
>  *
>  * @param int $pageId
>  * @return array
>  */
> protected function lookupStoreIds($newsId)
> {
>     $connection = $this->getConnection();
>
>     $select = $connection->select()->from(
>         $this->getTable('news_store'),
>         'store_id'
>     )->where(
>         TheNewInterface::NEWS_COLUMN_NEWS_ID . ' = ?',
>         (int)$newsId
>     );
>
>     return $connection->fetchCol($select);
> }
> ```

4. So now, the last step, you need to store your **store ids** in the field **store_id** of your News model. I did it so, in the app\code\Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\News.php I have the following code which is used to create an instance of the News model, which I use:

> ```
> /**
>  * Init TheNew
>  *
>  * @return TheNew $theNew
>  */
> protected function initTheNew()
> {
>     /** @var int - theNew id */
>     $theNewId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam(TheNewInterface::NEWS_COLUMN_NEWS_ID);
>
>     /** @var TheNewInterface $theNew */
>     $theNew = $this->theNewFactory->create();
>
>     if ($theNewId) {
>         $theNew = $this->theNewRepository->getById($theNewId);
>         $storesIds = $theNew->getCollection()->getStoreIdsByTheNewId($theNew->getId());
>         $theNew->setData('store_id', $storesIds);
>     }
>     $this->coreRegistry->register(TheNewInterface::TABLE_NEWS, $theNew);
>     return $theNew;
> }
> ```

If you don't have such a file, I hope, you got the idea and you can paste it somewhere else, for example, in your NewsRepository.php, if you have one.

That's it, now everything should be working.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE! If the question is answered in another question on here, please *flag* it as *duplicate*.

Comment: Okay guys, thx for the advices, I will edit my answer in 12 hours, when I'll have time for it.

Comment: Ok, now I pasted all the code, but it is displayed weirdly. What can I do? I pasted it in the <code> </code> tag