# How to show storeview in ui component grid in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, store-view

I want to show store-views in ui component grid. I am using this code in:

> /app/code/Mymodule/Myimages/view/adminhtml/ui_component/communieimages_name.xml

```
<column name="store_ids" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

but it is showing as blank. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue???
[image]

Comment: Try this ->https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99731/magento2-store-id-in-ui-listing-component

Comment: Any solutions about that?

Comment: @Keerthana did you found any solution about this?

Comment: @mahmoudismail please check below solution is works.

Answer (score 7):

I will solve this issue.

> /app/code/Mymodule/Myimages/view/adminhtml/ui_component/communieimages_name.xml

In this file Add this

```
<column name="store_ids" class="[vendorname]\[Modulename]\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Store">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">[vendorname]_[Modulename]/js/ui/grid/columns/html</item>
        <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
        <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

next, you have to create a class which is mention in the above ui_component File

> [vendorname]/[Modulename]/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Store.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\System\Store as SystemStore;

class Store extends \Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store
{
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        SystemStore $systemStore,
        Escaper $escaper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $systemStore, $escaper, $components, $data, 'store_ids');
    }

    protected function prepareItem(array $item)
    {
        $content = $origStores '';
        if (!is_null($item[$this->storeKey])) {
            $origStores = $item[$this->storeKey];
        }

        if (!is_array($origStores)) {
            $origStores = explode(',', $origStores);
        }
        if (in_array(0, $origStores) && count($origStores) == 1) {
            return __('All Store Views');
        }

        $data = $this->systemStore->getStoresStructure(false, $origStores);

        foreach ($data as $website) {
            $content .= $website['label'] . "<br/>";
            foreach ($website['children'] as $group) {
                $content .= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3) . $this->escaper->escapeHtml($group['label']) . "<br/>";
                foreach ($group['children'] as $store) {
                    $content .= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 6) . $this->escaper->escapeHtml($store['label']) . "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }

        return $content;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $this->prepareItem($item);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Next, you have to create a Component File that apply an Proper Formate view of your Store View in Admin Grid

this will mention in our ui_component File

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">[vendorname]_[Modulename]/js/ui/grid/columns/html</item>
```

create an html.js in the following path

> [vendorname]/[Modulename]/view/adminhtml/web/js/ui/grid/columns/html.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

return Component.extend({
     defaults: {
        bodyTmpl: 'ui/grid/cells/html'
     }
  });
});
```

**and make you Sure Store view Data do not store in an Array Formate. it has to convert into string formate and then it will store in the table.**

this will happen at the time of Save your Admin From or Edit Admin Form.

***add some line of code into your (Save or Edit) file given below***

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

if(!empty($data['store_ids'])) {
   $store_view = implode(',',$data['store_ids']);
   $this->request->setPostValue('store_ids',$store_view);
}
```

now you see Admin Gid will show you Store View as you want.

**I Hope This Helps You.**

Comment: I can't understand why you have created same file again in your module? Can't I use store module core file as a renderer directly? What is the difference?

Comment: @PatrickW  it can also achive using 'Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store' but there are a problem in our custom column name because in this class line number:62  is already define field name '$storeKey = 'store_id' so when we use this class store view not show that's why we create same file again in your module. if you want to use you must define field name 'store_id'.

Comment: I got your point. In my case, I am using column name as 'store_id' only. Still, when I save any record with 'All Store Views' value, it shows blank in grid. For specific store selection, it shows proper store name. Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: @patrickW  store view not show so used above code. because you have to find where this field name used. and i don't have any Idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Msquare is working fine, but you can apply the data cell renderer directly in the column xml. There is no need to create a custom js component for that.

```
<column name="store_ids" class="[vendorname]\[Modulename]\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Store">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
   <!-- Define the cell renderer here -->
   <settings>
       <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
   </settings>
   <!-- end renderer -->
</column>
```