# Magento Extension working in version 2.0 but not working in version 2.1

Tags: magento2, extensions, grid

I have developed a extension for Magento 2. I have doen all my development work in version 2.0.5. After completion of the development work, I tried to test it on Magento 2.1. But now I am facing problems.

On Magento 2.0 extension installed successfully and works great. But when I try to install it on Magento 2.1 then I receive the following error:

**Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
current version - none, required version - 1.0.0**

After this I have manually added 1.0.0 in data_version column of setup_module table.

Now after that admin panel works and I have tried to access my module then I got below error:

**Class PageGridDataProvider does not exist**

I am using this class in below code as per tutorial of Custom module in Magento 2.0

```
<dataSource name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PageGridDataProvider</argument>
        <!-- here we pass dataprovider name which i will define in di.xml file of module in next step -->
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

I am stuck at this error. Can anybody help me please. Is magento 2.1 require different extension development process?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have added below code in di.xml and now **Class PageGridDataProvider does not exist** error gone.

```
<virtualType name="PageGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"/>
```

Now can you help me out to solve the first issue. In which the data-version is not inserting during Installation and below error occours:

**Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
current version - none, required version - 1.0.0**

Comment: Can you show your di.xml?

Comment: have you seen this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98892/magento-2-why-does-a-ui-listing-component-need-two-collections ?

Comment: @chirag Thanks a lot mate. This answer helps me. Below code added in di.xml Now extension working in M 2.1

<virtualType name="PageGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"/>

Comment: i have posted this as answer feel free to accept. if this has solve your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this `di.xml` file.

The `PageGridDataProvider` resolves to a `virtualType`

```
<virtualType name="PageGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
...
</virtualType>
```

You can also refer [Magento 2: Why does a UI Listing Component need Two Collections?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98892/magento-2-why-does-a-ui-listing-component-need-two-collections)

It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should declare your PageGridDataProvider class in di.xml as virtual type as follow:

di.xml

```
<virtualType name="PageGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Vendor\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\PageGrid\Collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Then you should create your collection resource model for filling that data provider

`Vendor\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\PageGrid\Collection`

Edit: did you try to delete `var/generation` folder and flush caches?

Comment: Below code added in di.xml and works. Thanks for your help mate.  <virtualType name="PageGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"/>

Comment: upvote if it's working. Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and you will update version of the module and run the install/upgrade scripts for your module

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. current version - none, required version - 1.0.0

Hi Dheeraj,

Please run following command on cmd to solve this issue.

Step : 1 Access the bin folder of your project on cmd
Exp : -D:\server\htdocs\projectname\bin

Step 2:- Access the php.exe of your localserver
Exp : - D:\server\php\php.exe

Step 3:- And run the fbelow command on your cmd console

Exp :- D:\server\htdocs\projectname\bin> D:\server\php\php.exe magento setup:upgrade

If you facing in issue then ask me.